# Like query in C# Mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

In my project mongodb is used and linq is used to connect to mongodb.

This is the filter query created

```
builder.Where(x => x.OldBatchDesc.Contains(input.oldBatchDescription));
```

`Input` is model object and `oldBatchDescription` is property name. `OldBatchDesc` is column name.

In current scenario suppose user enters value ab in textbox this value is set to `input.oldBatchDescription`, and as per above query it will check in `OldBatchDesc` column which row will contain `ab`. For example if there are 5 rows in `OldBatchDesc` xyz, xyabz, def, defab, abcab, then it will return `xyabz, defab, abcab` as these contains `ab`.

Now the requirement is user will enter comma separated values in a textbox for example like `ab,xy,ef`, and I want to check whether `OldBatchDesc` column row will contain this values ab or xy or ef entered by user.

So in this scenario output will be xyz,xyabz,def,defab,abcab.

How to build a mongodb filter query for this using C#?

What I have done is created a string array and split it on comma

```
string[] desc = input.oldBatchDescription(',')
```

But how should I pass this array to filter query or is there any way to pass this comma separated values to filter to get desired output.

```
builder.Where(x => x.OldBatchDesc.Contains(input.oldBatchDescription));
```

Kindly guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, splitting would be nice. And then you can filter on each value whether present in the document field.

```
string[] desc = input.oldBatchDescription.Split(',');
builder.Where(x => desc.Any(d => x.Contains(d));
```

Try and let know how it goes.